# How to connect login forms to another forms? (I don't understand)

Tags: if-statement, authentication, c++builder, c++builder-6

This is my first time joining a developer forum to learn coding for my college. C++Builder 6 is used in my department.

I am learning how to use simple login forms.  I want to try to make a "Login" button access another form (or `.cpp`), such as a database system, if login is successful.  I don't know what code to use for this.

I found this, but I cannot figure it out (because I am a new student and I don't know anything about app coding):

```
login.cpp --> Press "login" --> "If-statement" --> "ShowMessage" --> database.cpp
```

What code can I use to access another form in an `if` statement?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the pics. Wait for moment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to better understand how to ask questions here, and what kind of questions to ask.  We are not here to give you tutorials, or write code for you. Please put in the effort to first talk to your school teacher and write some code yourself, and then come back and ask specific questions here if you run into issues with it.

Comment: In C++Builder, a Form is just like any other C++ class, just with a GUI attached to it at runtime. So you should be focusing on the the basics of how to write different classes in the same `.cpp` file that access each other, and then focus on how to make them access each other across `.cpp` files. If your school course hasn't covered classes, pointers/references, and object access yet, you are jumping ahead of yourself.  Don't focus on the GUI, that will come later after you understand how classes work.